# Pass GoogleApiClient to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-signin

I've already read the related topisc but I couldn't find the solution.
I need to do the logout in another activity where the GoogleApiClient is declared.
In the logout activity I use this code to do the logout

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(myGoogleApiClient);
```

To get myGoogleApiClient I tried initializing the mGoogleApiClient "public static" in the LoginActivity and also I tried with singleton getting the instance of the class and then getting the client.

But I always get the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add connect function

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // Get sign out result
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
});
```